# other way to make start up menu instead using button

Tags: android, button, menu

i am thinking of doing a start up menu before going into the real page like the picture below.

[image]

i think i can do it with button menu. so, the pikpok, all-star, etc i made it using button widget. Is there any other way to make this?

anyway, when user click on all-star button, it appear to the next xml file. but then the activity seems not working out.

this is my code. this code shows the start up activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {                                
                setContentView(R.layout.about);
            }

        });

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {                                
                setContentView(R.layout.report);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

report.xml and about.xml will have their own activity named ReportActivity and AboutActivity but it does not work.

is there a better way to the start up menu instead of using button. also it would be nice if the menu could have animation to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rather complex "Buttons" you can define your own View by using layouts/images/other view

check

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

for more information.

To call another activity, you have to define an activity class for that activity first, which calls the layout etc. On how to start another activity read

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity